# Can I have OrmLite use lowercase for PostgreSQL column names rather than the provided lowercase with underbar naming?

Tags: postgresql, ormlite-servicestack

I am looking into ServiceStack and am using OrmLite against a PostgreSQL database.  I have created my POCO class as shown:

```
public class Company
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLicenses { get; set; }
}
```

I also setup the database connection in the Global.asax file as per the directions on the SS site.  Here is that code:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
                c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Server=localhost;Port=5432;SearchPath=company;Database=company;User Id=ABC; Password=XYZ;", PostgreSqlDialect.Provider)
                {
                    ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
                });
```

As you can see, I have the PostgreSQL dialect provider and mini-profiler in play.  Since I am testing, I am just adding fake data here as well:

```
using (IDbConnection db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
            {
                db.Insert(new Company { CompanyName = "Company A", NumberOfLicenses = 13});
                db.Insert(new Company { CompanyName = "Company B", NumberOfLicenses = 82});
                db.Insert(new Company { CompanyName = "Company C", NumberOfLicenses = 16});
                db.Insert(new Company { CompanyName = "Company D", NumberOfLicenses = 8});
                db.Insert(new Company { CompanyName = "Company E", NumberOfLicenses = 107});
                db.Insert(new Company { CompanyName = "Company F", NumberOfLicenses = 56});
            }
```

When I run the application, I get the error: ERROR: 42703: column "company_name" of relation "company" does not exist

This makes sense, because my database has a column named companyname, not company_name in the company table.  PostgreSQL is particular about case, so I made my column names all lower case.  However, my POCO properties are camel case.  It looks like the PostgreSQL provider code is forcing camelcase properties to be named with an _ symbol in between each capital letter.  In the database I temporarily renamed the companyname column to company_name, and sure enough, the error moved to the NumberOfLicenses property, which became number_of_licenses.

Can I change this behavior so that my POCO properties map to lowercase without the _ symbol?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use specify your own naming strategy with:

```
public class LowercaseNamingStrategy : OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase
{
    public override string GetTableName(string name)
    {
        return name.ToLower();
    }

    public override string GetColumnName(string name)
    {
        return name.ToLower();
    }

}

OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.NamingStrategy = new LowercaseNamingStrategy();
```